# Getting error Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in register.php on line 20

Tags: php, database, authentication

I downloaded login php script from GitHub ([Link to it](https://github.com/thedevdojo/php-login-script)) and when I try to register, it displays me this error: `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /homework/register.php on line 20`
On login page it doesn't show any errors.

Code that I was using:

```
 <?php

    session_start();

    if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
        header("Location: /");
    }

    require 'database.php';

    $message = '';

    if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

        // Enter the new user in the database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

        if( $stmt->execute() ):
            $message = 'Successfully created new user';
        else:
            $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
        endif;

    endif;

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Register Below</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="header">
            <a href="/">Homework</a>
        </div>

        <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
            <p><?= $message ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <h1>Register</h1>
        <span>or <a href="login.php">login here</a></span>

        <form action="register.php" method="POST">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="and password" name="password">
            <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" name="confirm_password">
            <input type="submit">

        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

database.php (if needed):

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'my_username';
$password = 'my_password';
$database = 'my_dbname';

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die( "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Database is working fine. Not getting errors.

Can someone explain what is going wrong with registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing a value to `bind_param()`, you need to pass a variable and not the return value from a function...

```
$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

to...

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

When you see a parameter with a `&` in front of it as in `&$variable` in...

> public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed
>   &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed
>   $driver_options ]]] )

You need to pass a variable.